# Opening a Symfony 1.4 Project made with a previous version of Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, symfony-1.4

Today I found an issue opening a project made with **Netbeans 7.1.2** in **Netbeans 7.3**.

Inspecting the project, several exclamation marks were founded, and the following code appears to be invalid:

```
class ##MODULE_NAME##Actions extends auto##MODULE_NAME##Actions
{
 //...
}
```

The right syntax is:

```
class Actions extends  Actions
{
 //...
}
```

Does anyone have a clue about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First syntax is for symfony admin generator, ##MODULE_NAME## is substituted by proper module name on generate process.

Nothing to worry about.

Comment: My concern was related to import projects made with older versions of Netbeans, because 7.3 makes this changes to several classes, and the project seems to be invalid...